# Can programmers.SE be extended?

Tags: discussion

Can Programmers.SE be extended to include more features.

1. Is there an API available?
2. If available, What can be done with the API?
3. What languages does it support?

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to do?

There is an API - [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) with which you can write **read-only** applications.

People have also written Greasemonkey scripts to extend the UI - also listed on the Apps site.

Translation isn't currently available, but I would be very surprised if there hadn't been discussions about this as it's been raised several times on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I am thinking about a machine-learning service

Comment: @Ubermensch Another option are the [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/). I don't think that's what you're after, but just to let you know...